# Refused to execute script because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, disable X-Content-Type-Options header?

Tags: javascript, html

I have page A and page B. Page A has `<script>` with `src` pointing to some page B url, and some script is returned from this url.

And this script is not executing, because of the error

> Refused to execute script from 'pageB/url' because its MIME type
>   ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is
>   enabled.

Also, there is a response header in page B

> X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

As far as I understand, this header is causing trouble, but how can I disable it? Or is it the problem with page A not B?

Comment: use cors at server side.